# After changing a list value and running the function again, the value resets to what it originally was

Tags: python, matrix, indexing, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a Tic Tac Toe game for a school project and made a function that takes in two parameters (`row` and `col`) and makes a `Position` object out of them. A `Position` object has an attribute `index` which makes a `list` out of its `self.row` and `self.col` values. The function is a method for a `class` `Player`.

Code snippet 1:

```
def getTurnCoordinates(self):
        row = int(input('In which row would you like to place the symbol ' + self.symbol + '?: '))
        col = int(input('In which column would you like to place the symbol ' + self.symbol + '?: '))
        pos = Position(row, col, self.symbol)
        if pos.isTaken():
            print("Position taken. Please choose another.")
            self.getTurnCoordinates()
        else:
            self.board.setPosition(pos.index, self.symbol)
            return self.board.getBoard()
```

This is the method for getting the parameters. Its purpose is to get `int` values which will later on be used to change the value of a specific index in a matrix `Board`.

Code snippet 2:

```
class Board(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ROWS = COLS = 3
        self.board = [[Position(i%ROWS, i%COLS, ' ').symbol for i in range(COLS)] for i in range(ROWS)]
        self.display = f"""
 Tic  Tac  Toe
{self.getBoard()}
  0    1    2"""

    def getBoard(self):
        return '\n'.join(map(str, self.board))
        
    def setPosition(self, position, sym):
        self.board[position[0]][position[1]] = sym

    def getPosition(self, position: list):
        return self.board[position[0]][position[1]]
```

This second code snippet is all of the `Board` `class` methods used in the former function.
When I run my `main.py` file, I get this output.

main.py:

```
from classes.board import Board
from classes.player import Player

b = Board()

print(b.display)

p1 = Player('X')
p2 = Player('O')
players = Player.playerList

for ply in players:
    print(ply.getTurnCoordinates())
```

Output:

```
Tic  Tac  Toe
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
  0    1    2
In which row would you like to place the symbol X?: 0
In which column would you like to place the symbol X?: 0
['X', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
In which row would you like to place the symbol O?: 0
In which column would you like to place the symbol O?: 1
[' ', 'O', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
>>>
```

Each time the function is run, the original `Board` object resets all of its indices to `' '`. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It seems the `Player` class keeps the `board` as an attribute. Could it be that each instantiation has a different board? `Player` has no reason to interact with the board. It should only contain functionality about the player, i.e., requesting coordinates and the symbol. You should have a `Game` class which takes care of turns and communicates information between `Player` and `Board`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `Player` object has a separate `self.board`. The code is not replacing the board with its previous values; it is displaying a different board which is still in its initial configuration.

You'll want to rethink your classes and their relationships. I would design this as one `Board` class with two `Player` instances, but you could certainly also make each `Player` independent and have its `__init__` method receive a reference to a shared `Board`.

Answer (score 0):

You never seem to pass the board to the actual players in `main.py`. To what does `self.board`in `getTurnCoordinates()` refer?

Comment: While you're most likely right, your answer is less of an answer and more of a comment. Use those to ask for clarification instead if you feel your answer is taking a stab in the dark.

Comment: I would really like to just comment but I can't. I didn't reach the 50 reputation limit yet which is really frustrating.

Comment: [Answers shouldn't be used to bypass the reputation threshold for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Even so, you did try to answer the question so that's fine.